How to pass rust polars DataFrame to python object?
I know there's this question. However the code I want is a little different.
[dependencies]
ordered-float: "4.4"
polars: {version="0.43", features = ["lazy", "parquet", "dtype-struct", "dtype-u8", "round_series"]}
itertools = "0.13"
chrono: "0.4"
pyo3: { version = "0.21", features = ["extension-module"] }
pyo3-polars: "0.18"
I want this to work:
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3::{Python, IntoPy};
use polars::prelude::*;
use pyo3_polars::PyDataFrame;

fn get_df() -> DataFrame{
    let mut symbols: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
    let mut prices: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
    df!(
        "Symbol" => &symbols,
        "Price" => &prices
    ).unwrap()
}
fn to_python() -> PyResult<PyDataFrame> {
    let df:DataFrame = get_df(); 
    let pydf = PyDataFrame(df);
    Python::with_gil(|py| {
        Ok(pydf)
    })
}

However I got:
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/lib.rs:62:32
    |
62  |         let pydf = PyDataFrame(df);
    |                    ----------- ^^ expected `polars_core::frame::DataFrame`, found `polars::prelude::DataFrame`
    |                    |
    |                    arguments to this struct are incorrect
    |
    = note: `polars::prelude::DataFrame` and `polars_core::frame::DataFrame` have similar names, but are actually distinct types

How to solve this? Thank you!

It looks like you've got different version of polars. Please put the output of cargo tree.

@ChayimFriedman Here is the cargo tree: https://gist.github.com/xuJ14/85c67a168a93f130c4296b9994d3aa4a

@ChayimFriedman You are right! The polars in pyo3-polars is different with my cargo.toml. Thank you!
